# Sort data before using numpy.median

Tags: python, numpy, median, percentile

I'm measuring the median and percentiles of a sample of data using Python.

```
import numpy as np
xmedian=np.median(data)
x25=np.percentile(data, 25)
x75=np.percentile(data, 75)
```

Do I have to use the `np.sort()` function on my data before measuring the median?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`numpy.median`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html#numpy.median), you don't have to manually sort the data before feeding it to the function, as it does this internally. It is actually very good practice to view the source-code of the function, and try to understand how it works.

Example, showing that sorting beforehand is unnecessary:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data = np.array([[ 10, 23,  1,  4,  5],
   ...:                  [  2, 12,  5, 22, 14]])

In [3]: median = np.median(data)  # Median of unsorted data

In [4]: median
Out[4]: 7.5

In [5]: data.sort()  # Sorting data

In [6]: median_sorted = np.median(data.ravel())  # Median of the flattened array

In [7]: median_sorted
Out[7]: 7.5

In [8]: median == median_sorted  # Check that they are equal
Out[8]: True
```